Benefits of a United Kingdom passport for minors of foreign origin born to nationals holding foreign citizenship
Both my wife and I hold Indian citizenship.  We have been residing in the United Kingdom for the past 4 years. Last year we were blessed with our daughter, born in the United Kingdom. Since neither of us has permanent residency, our daughter was born an Indian citizen.
Next year, she will become eligible for British citizenship after one of us becomes a permanent resident of the United Kingdom.
However, we have been offered a potential career opportunity in Singapore. If we take this opportunity, we are going to be much closer to our roots and family. Hence, it is an attractive offer.
So we are currently weighing how important this one factor is.
So, what are the short-term and long-term benefits of being a British passport holder / overseas citizen? Are there any cons?

What has your own research on this topic revealed?

The UK has a few classes of nationality that have the word "overseas" in their name, including "British overseas citizen."  These are for people who are associated with one of the overseas territories.  Your daughter would not be a British overseas citizen; she would be a British citizen.

Long-term benefits are primarily the ability to reside in the UK and Ireland without a visa, along with lighter visa requirements for visits in Europe and North America (and probably elsewhere; I don't know for sure); the main disadvantage is loss of Indian citizenship, but this is significantly mitigated by Overseas Citizenship of India (OCI), which I believe would allow her to reside indefinitely in India should you decide to return, and possibly to regain Indian citizenship relatively easily if she decides to do that (although she would have to renounce her British citizenship unless India were to change its nationality law in the meanwhile).
For more information, see these pages at Wikipedia:

Visa requirements for British citizens
Visa requirements for Indian citizens
Overseas Citizenship of India

